# jquery dialog and selectable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a bunch of divs that display text.

I have made these selectable and what I'm ideally looking to do is be able to change the font size of the text for the selected div.

I have a dialog that has a basic form with the font sizes in a select list, but I'm struggling to find a way to actually target the selectable from within the dialog.

```
$(function(){
    $('#template_inner').selectable({
           selected: function(event, ui){
            console.log(ui);
            // displays the HTML in the console

        }
    })


$( "#font-size-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 200,
    width: 270,
    modal: true,
    position: ['top', 200],
    buttons: {
        "Select": function() {
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function() {
    }
});

   $( ".font-size" )
       .button()
       .click(function() {
           $( "#font-size-form" ).dialog( "open" );
   });
});


<div id="font-size-form" title="Choose Font Size">
    <form action="" method="">
        <p>Please choose your font-size</p>
        <div class="">
            <select name="size">
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="32">32</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

So, when I click on the div, then click to open the font size dialog box, select the font size, I'd like to change the font size of the text in the div.

Is this possible?

Many thanks

Comment: u want to change the font when u select the div(containing text) or when u chose the font size

Comment: When I change the font size from the select list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have to remember the selection for the duration of the page, then you could save the font size as data (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/data/)) on the selectable.

```
//in your dialog
"Select": function() {
  $('#template_inner .ui-selected').css('font-size', $('select[name="size"]').val() + 'px');
  $('#template_inner').data('fontSize', $('select[name="size"]').val());
}

//on your selectable
$('#template_inner').selectable({
  selected: function(event, ui){
    var defaultSize = 22;
    // Get the saved value or default on new selects.
    var size = $('#template_inner').data('fontSize') || defaultSize;
    $(ui.selected).css('font-size', size + 'px');
  }
})
```

Comment: I have tried to use the code that you have provided. When selecting a div, the font changes to 22px. But when I select a font size and click 'Select', then nothing changes.

Comment: @user789122 Did you look at the output of the `Select` function? The jQuery selector for the select might be wrong, you could add a class or an id to the select.

Comment: I have added an `id` to the select and targeted the `.val()` for that and it seems to have worked!

Comment: @user789122 Removing the space in `select [name="size"]` also worked